# Do i have to sanitize while listing values from database?

Tags: php, xss, filter-var

About PDO want to be sure if i do right or wrong while sanitizing values after select queries especially while avoiding xss attacks.

```
$cagri_durumb = 1;
$bek_servis = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM cagri_kayitlari INNER JOIN 
personeller ON cagri_kayitlari.cagri_servis_perid = personeller.per_id WHERE 
cagri_durum = :cagri_durum AND cagri_islem_tarihi NOT BETWEEN :bugun AND 
:yarin');                           
$bek_servis->bindParam(':cagri_durum', $cagri_durumb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$bek_servis->bindParam(':bugun', $bugun, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$bek_servis->bindParam(':yarin', $yarin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$bek_servis ->execute();
$bek_servisa = $bek_servis->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($bek_servisa as $servisa){

echo '<a href="servisbasla.php?id='.filter_var($servisa["cagri_id"], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT).'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
title="'.filter_var($servisa['cagri_sebep'],  
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING).'">'.filter_var($servisa["cari_unvan"], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING).'</a> - '.filter_var($servisa["per_isim"], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING).' / 
'.date("d.m.Y",strtotime($servisa['cagri_islem_tarihi'])).'<br />';}
```

Do i have to use FILTER_SANITIZE.. filters in each echo's while listing values from database?

And if i have to use them, for text values, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter is totally enough?

Comment: If you clear/sanitize variables when inserting into database, I don't think you need to re-sanitize them when displaying

Comment: If you have control over input process and you do sanitize your data then, then its overkill and completely useless to sanitize your data again on output. Imagine if we did that on airports ... if we had to put our luggage again for check when we land.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As i said i wanted to be sure and i got what i needed. Airport example is clear enough :) Thanks..